# AspectJ Load Time Weaving - Command Line Project

Tags: java, command-line, jar, aspectj, load-time-weaving

i am struggling since days on a simple project that i just can't get to run.

My goal is to extend the functionality of a .jar-File in order to get more information about the inner workings of that jar. The .jar is not open source.
I came accross a lot of different concepts to "inject" my own code into the jvm like the "ASM"-Library, BECL, Javassist and finally AspectJ.

AspectJ caught my attention as it seems to be easier to use and more high level. To try how AspectJ is working before using it with the closed source .jar, i set up Test-Projects:

**Project1:**

To test it, i wanted to create a simply project containing one Class that should be compiled and packed to a .jar-File. This class should later be monitored using the Aspect. I took the Source Code of this Class from an example on the internet: https://github.com/Nosfert/AspectJ-Tutorial-jayway
The file content of the class looks like this:
YourClass.java:

```
package com.test.java.instrumentation;

public class YourClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
        yourClass.yourMethodBefore();
        yourClass.yourMethodAfter();
        yourClass.yourMethodAround(1);
        yourClass.yourMethodAround(1,"Test");
    }

    public void yourMethodBefore() {
        System.out.println("Executing TestTarget.yourMethodBefore()");
    }

    public void yourMethodAfter(){
        System.out.println("Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAfter()");
    }

    public void yourMethodAround(Integer i){
        System.out.println("Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAround()");
        System.out.println("i : "+i);
    }

    public void yourMethodAround(Integer i,String x){
        System.out.println("Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAround()");
        System.out.println("i : "+i);
        System.out.println("x : "+x);
    }
}
```

I compile the code with the following command:

```
javac -d bin -cp ./src/ ./src/com/test/java/instrumentation/YourClass.java
```

The command runs without errors.
In the next step i created a Manifest file containing the necessary information to run the Class in a .jar-File:
MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.test.java.instrumentation.YourClass
Built-By: Me
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
```

In the next step i create a .jar:

```
cd bin\
jar cvfm program.jar ..\meta-inf\manifest.mf .
```

The .jar can be successfully executed via:

```
java -jar program.jar
```

The output looks like this:

```
Executing TestTarget.yourMethodBefore()
Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAfter()
Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAround()
i : 1
Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAround()
i : 1
x : Test
```

So far so good. Step 1 is completed. This is the example-application that should later be expanded with additional functionality using AspectJ's Load Time Weaving.

**Project2:**
In the next step i want to create the AspectJ .jar-File containing my code to expand the functionality of Project1:
The contents of Priject2 (YourAspect.java) is the following:

```
package com.test.java.instrumentation;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;

@Aspect
public class YourAspect {

    //Patterns
    //blank = modifier (public/private/protected or default(blank) should be looked for
    //* = return type to look for. Void/Object/Primitive type
    //com.jayway.YourClass.yourMethodBefore(..) = PackageName . ClassName . methodName (parameters)
    @Before("execution (* com.test.java.instrumentation.YourClass.yourMethodBefore(..))")
    //JointPoint = the reference of the call to the method
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("YourAspect's BeforeAdvice's body is now executed Before yourMethodBefore is called.");
    }
    //Patterns
    //public = look for the specific modifier named public
    //!Object = Basically we are looking for void or primitives. But if we specified Object we could get a good pattern
    //com.jayway.YourClass.yourMethodBefore(..) = PackageName . ClassName . methodName (parameters)
    @After("execution (public !Object com.test.java.instrumentation.YourClass.yourMethodAfter(..))")
    public void afterAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("YourAspect's afterAdvice's body is now executed After yourMethodAfter is called.");
    }
    //Patterns
    //!private = look for any modifier that's not private
    //void = looking for method with void
    //com.jayway.YourClass.yourMethodBefore(..) = PackageName . ClassName . methodName (parameters)
    @Around("execution (!private void com.test.java.instrumentation.YourClass.yourMethodAround(Integer,..))")
    //ProceedingJointPoint = the reference of the call to the method.
    //The difference between ProceedingJointPoint and JointPoint is that a JointPoint can't be continued (proceeded)
    //A ProceedingJointPoint can be continued (proceeded) and is needed for an Around advice
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //Default Object that we can use to return to the consumer
        Object returnObject = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("YourAspect's aroundAdvice's body is now executed Before yourMethodAround is called.");
            //We choose to continue the call to the method in question
            returnObject = joinPoint.proceed();
            //If no exception is thrown we should land here and we can modify the returnObject, if we want to.
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            //Here we can catch and modify any exceptions that are called
            //We could potentially not throw the exception to the caller and instead return "null" or a default object.
            throw throwable;
        }
        finally {
            //If we want to be sure that some of our code is executed even if we get an exception
            System.out.println("YourAspect's aroundAdvice's body is now executed After yourMethodAround is called.");
        }

        return returnObject;
    }
    //Patterns
    //blank = modifier (public/private/protected or default(blank) should be looked for
    //* = return type to look for. Void/Object/Primitive type
    //com.jayway.YourClass.yourMethod*(..) = PackageName . ClassName . * (parameters)
    //Where the "*" will catch any method name
    @After("execution ( * com.test.java.instrumentation.YourClass.*(..))")
    //JointPoint = the reference of the call to the method
    public void printNewLine(JoinPoint pointcut){
        //Just prints new lines after each method that's executed in
        System.out.print("\n\r");
    }
}
```

I also created a MANIFEST.FM:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.test.java.instrumentation.YourAspect
Built-By: Me
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
```

And a aop.xml:

```
<aspectj>

    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.test.java.instrumentation.YourAspect"/>
   </aspects>

   <weaver options="-XlazyTjp">
       <include within="com.test.java.instrumentation..*"/>
   </weaver>

</aspectj>
```

I can compile the class successfully with the following command:

```
javac -cp ./lib/aspectjrt.jar;.lib/aspejctjweaver.jar;./src;. -d ./bin/ ./src/com/test/java/instrumentation/YourAspect.java
```

The resulting classfile is packaged together with the Manifest and the aop.xml into a .jar:

```
cd bin\
jar cvfm aspect.jar ..\meta-inf\manifest.mf ..\meta-inf\aop.xml .
```

When i try to run the example-program (Project1) and try to weave the aspect (Project2), i am using the following command:

```
java -Daj.weaving.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true -javaagent:./Aspect/lib/aspectjweaver.jar -cp ./Aspect/lib/aspectjrt.jar;./Aspect/lib/aspejctjtools.jar;. -jar ./JavaProgram/bin/program.jar
```

The load fails and the resulting error is the following:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.10 built on Monday Dec 12, 2016 at 19:07:48 GMT
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info no configuration found. Disabling weaver for class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
Executing TestTarget.yourMethodBefore()
Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAfter()
Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAround()
i : 1
Executing TestTarget.yourMethodAround()
i : 1
x : Test
```

How can i injecte my aspect (Project2) into the running program.jar (Project1)?
Do you have any ideas?

I attached all the files including Sourcecode and Manifests that i created (Both projects) as a .zip-File in the following link, so you can also try out what i did so far. This might help you to spot my errors easier. The project is designed to run on windows commandline.

Link: [Downloadlink of my Projects](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12488455/AspectBeispiel.zip.html)

Thank you very much for your Ideas!

Comment: First of all, it's sketchy to upload zipped executables.  Host the source next time.  Anyways, your compilation command looks a bit off - shouldn't the .jar be following the -cp option? It looks like that's keeping the compilation from completing like it should. Can you provide the name of the .jar you are trying to work with? Or the source? Look at your resulting .jar contents - it only contains your sample class.

Comment: The .zip file contains the sourcecode, the compile commands and the directory structure including the .jar files. Dont run the .jars, if you dont trust them.
Both compilations are working fine, they don't throw errors.
As i said, the sources are included in the .zip file.

Comment: Did anyone find any solution to this? I'm also stuck at the same problem

Comment: @HurrDurr did you find any solution to this?